# Null values in CSV causing issue in moving data to mysql through python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I don't have control over the `null` values in `csv` because it being uploaded by different system, but when I try to move the data from `csv` to `mysql` facing issue in `null` values. It is a nullable column there is no constraint.
Sample values:

subject_name    subject_code    subject_type    description
Pyro                PY          Major       Pyrotechnic
Techy                           Elective    This is a subject
Biology             BIO         Major       This is a subject
Zoology             Zoo         Major       This is a subject

Python insert's first row and terminating with mysql error message.

```
Error Message: There is no traceback I just received below error message
Error while connecting to MySQL 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'
```

Note: code is working fine if there is no null in csv.
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlCti.png)

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys
import datetime
filePath = str(sys.argv[1])
df = pd.read_csv(filePath)
df.head()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
        #here %S means string values
        value = None
        sql = "INSERT INTO simple.subj_stg VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row.to_list() + [cre_usr_id,actn_usr_id,updt_usr_id,cre_ts]) )
        print("Record inserted")
        # the connection is not auto committed by default, so we must commit to save our changes
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: this is not a direct answer, but sqlalchemy is very useful for connecting python <> database for such operations.

Comment: can you post values of  `i` and `row` where it fails?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which row and column makes problem. And you use pandas so you can some use functions to replace `null` in all `dataframe` at once - so you CAN control `null` values.

Comment: all values in `sys.argv` are strings and you don't need `str()`

Comment: error rather suggests you use wrong name for column, not value in row.

Comment: pandas has [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to write without using `for`-loop

Comment: @furas - no column name is fine because when the sample data is full without nulls the whole process runs as expected, I receive error only when the sample data is null.

Comment: Thanks @furas I used df.fillna("Null", inplace = True) to fill empty values in csv as null, now i could able to insert rows in mysql

Comment: you can put it as answer below - and later you can mark your answer as accepted and people will see that problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

fill the empty columns with df.fillna("Null", inplace = True) then run the insert statement to mysql from python